# Finding a tangent plane equation

Tags: tangent-line

> I have to find the tangent plane equation to the surface $zx^2+xy^2+yz^2=5$ at the point of $(-1,1,2)$.

I couldn't get the right answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What did you try?

Comment: I equalized it to 0 and tried to write it as F(x,y,z)

Comment: Please show any attempts you have made *in* the post, not in the comments.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you’d like someone to point out what you did wrong instead of simply feeding you a solution, then include your work in the question. “I equalized it to $0$...” really doesn’t tell us much about what it is you did. For one thing, what is “it” in that sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x,y,z) = zx^2 +xy^2 +yz^2 $. The normal vector of the curve at the point $(-1,1,2)$ is

$$(f_x,f_y,f_z)=(2xz+y^2,2xy+z^2,2yz+x^2) =(-3,2,5)$$

Then, the equation of the plane is given by

$$(x+1,y-1,z-2)\cdot (-3,2,5) =0$$